# connect to mysql through php with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection

I'm working with php and trying to make a connection to mysql with pdo. I've read that I must have pdo extension first (don't know if I do, neither how to check it). I've changed the config.inc.php file of phpmyadmin to aloud external connections. Looks like this:

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '8000';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';  ////I've also try with config here
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'xxxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'xxxxx';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = true;

?>
```

my php file is like this:

```
function connect() {
    global $pdo;
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:8000;dbname=sakila", "xxxx", "xxxxxx");
}

function get_actors_by_last_name($letter){
    global $pdo;

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
        SELECT actor_id, first_name, get_actors_by_last_name
        from  actor
        where first_name like :letter
        limit 50');


    $stmt->execute(  array(':letter' => $letter . '%' ));


    return $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

}

?>
```

The page is a simple form that is suppose to bring the names of actors depending on the first letter of their name. Every time you try to make it work the page stock while loading, without bring me anything, not a problem or exception. if I change the host parameter and put the hostname value that is using my mysql like this (in the real code the real host value):

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql.value;dbname=sakila", "xxxx", "xxxxxx");
```

I get an this message:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'x.x.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server' in /Users/josecarro/Desktop/jquery/ajax/dataBase/functions.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /Users/josecarro/Desktop/jquery/ajax/dataBase/functions.php(13): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=MacB...', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', NULL) #1 /Users/josecarro/Desktop/jquery/ajax/dataBase/index.php(7): connect() #2 {main} thrown in /Users/josecarro/Desktop/jquery/ajax/dataBase/functions.php on line 13

that leads me to believe that actually pdo extension is working.
To open the server and using this line on terminal on the directory where my files are:

```
open http://localhost:8000 && python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

and on the same directory I'm starting php with

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

I don't know whats the problem. Although I believe I have pdo I've tried to install it with phpbrew (just in case), installing another php version (7.0.7). But I get stock when I try to install the extensions with

```
phpbrew ext install pdo-mysql
```

Actually I really don't know what the hell I'm doing. I've seen in the php documentation that you must compile like this:

```
--with-pdo-mysql[=DIR]
```

I don't know what does it means… I'm pretty lost, as you can see. I think its probably easier than I think, but I don't know how to do it, what to change. HELP PLEASE!!!

Comment: You are confusing http port with database port

Comment: are you talking about the php file? on the pdo line? do i have to take off the port and just put 'host=localhost;' ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes I would make here, Instead of having your PDO as a function, create a new page called 'connection.php' and include it on any page where you need to connect. EX:

```
<?php
    try{
    $pdo= new PDO("mysql:dbname=NAME; host=localhost; charset=utf8", "username", "password");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

    ?>
```

To include the page:

```
include('connection.php');
```

or

```
require_once('connection.php');
```

Change

```
return $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

to

```
$result[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then iterate each result in a foreach loop, depending on how many external arrays you have before the result set you may need 1-2 foreach loops.

EX:

```
foreach($result as subResult){
    foreach($subresult as $rows){
        echo $rows['actor_id'];
        //or do a var_dump($rows);
    }

}
```